# sIFR Doesn't Work in FF3 Mac

Tags: macos, firefox, sifr

I thought it might be something I was doing wrong, but I am not seeing it working on any site, including Novemberborn.net.

Any Ideas? The CSS is loaded, so the headlines are hidden, and then it is like the JS isn't loaded at all.

Could this be a browser detection issue?

I am using firefox 3 with latest flash player version 10. I have heard the complaint from other Mac users as well.

Works on every other browser...

EDIT: I removed the CSS to hide, it still doesn't work. After a pause, it loads the JS and removes the headlines, but doesn't replace them.

Comment: Also. I am seeing that it works on some macs and not on others. And this across the board on every site, not just mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you're using the AdBlock extension. It breaks Flash under Firefox 3. You'll have to completely uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks so much Mark! That was completely baffling me. I built a Mac/FF3 detection script that sees if Adblock is running and then disables, so the text still shows up. Isn't full proof, but works for now. You can see it in my Wordpress plugin WP sIFR at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-sifr/

Comment: Cool. How are you doing the Adblock detection?

Comment: After I figure out a user is on a mac w/firefox, I set a variable to false. Then I ask the brower to load a javascript that sets the variable to true. The javascript is named ads.js?ad=http://ad.doubleclick.net/... To trick adblock. If it gets blocked i don't load sifr.

Comment: I got the idea here: http://ohryan.ca/blog/2007/08/20/whyfirefoxisblock-is-wrong-adblock-plus-is-100-detectable/comment-page-1/#comment-2201

This is the ad js i am using: ads.js?ad=http://ad.doubleclick.net/ad/amazon.pixel.qos/;pixid=3;sz=1x1;ord=1236894759792?

Which i got from an Amazon ad. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply disabling (not uninstalling) AdBlock/Filterset.G resolved the issue in Firefox 3 on Windows. However, it turns out AdBlock/Filterset.G has been superseded by [AdBlock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865) anyway. (Somehow I had completely missed that, after years of doing incremental updates to Firefox.)

sIFR 3 does appear to be compatible with the newer [AdBlock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865).

Answer (score 0):

There is a WordPress sIFR plugin that somehow detects adblock on a mac and disables sIFR if it is active. The hack is somewhere in that code... I'm still looking for the way to do it. That way, the text will still be displayed like it's supposed to be.

Google: sIFR firefox 3 adblock

Comment: Ha. I actually wrote that plugin (wp-sIFR) and am using the method above.